# Compiler Error C2758 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have this lines:

```
class ModulePeople : public Module {
public:
   std::list<People> & list_people;
   std::list<People>::iterator it;
}
```

When I try to compile I have this error:

```
Compiler Error C2758 
'ModulePeople': a member of reference type must be initialized
```

This error appears in this line for example:

```
it = list_people.begin();
```

But I don't really know how to inicializate this kind of variable, because i can't do it to NULL. If somebody can help me it would be very grateful.

Comment: Please post code that reproduces your error

Comment: This error appears in this line for example:

it = list_people.begin();

Comment: My appologies, I copied bad. Edited

Comment: Your member `list_people` is a reference this must be initialised in your ctor

Comment: I know, but i don't know how to initialise list_people, because i can't use NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reference is an alias for an existing object with storage space somewhere. This means that a reference must reference (no pun intended) an existing object, it's not like a pointer which can has value of `nullptr`.

This implies that if you use a reference as a member field of a class definition then you must initialize it through any available constructor of such object, eg:

```
class ModulePeople : public Module {
public:
   std::list<People> & list_people;
   std::list<People>::iterator it;

   ModulePeople(decltype(list_people) list_people) : list_people(list_people) { }
}
```

If you really want to be able to let it point to nothing then could use a pointer instead, eg `std::list<People>*`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :D